# VScode formatter 'black' for python installing error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatter

Long story short, I try to install black formatter for python in VScode and I get this :

```
a_lex@HOME MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tutorial
$ "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe" c:\Users\a_lex\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.4.765268190\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U black --user
C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'c:Usersa_lex.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2021.4.765268190pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any reasons why?

Comment: mingw does not understand \ as file separator, the file `c:Usersa_lex.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2021.4.765268190pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py` does not exist

Comment: why use a bash shell (mingw) to start a Win Python install (`C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe`)

Comment: @Alex Aly -Please try to install the module "black" using the command "_pip install black_" in the "Terminal" of VS Code. For using "formatting" in VS Code, you could refer to this document: [Formatting in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).